# Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName) - No such host is known

Tags: c#, sockets, dns, socketexception

As the title suggests I get the socket exception : 'No such host is known', when calling the Dns.GetHostEntry method.

Dns.GetHostName is used to find the hostname for the machine.

I understand the host name that gets resolved using Dns.GetHostName could be the reason behind the socket exception. I am trying to understand what could possibly cause varying results resolving host name using the GetHostName method. Could it be the environment?

The socket exception is random and is in intranet environment and not every user gets this. I do not believe a FQDN could be a reason as i have tested in my machine where the resolved hostname was a short name.

The code is as below:

```
 var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
 var entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
```

Additionally what are the possible alternatives to Dns.GetHostName?

Comment: Well what is the value of `hostName` when the exception happens?

Comment: Why would you want an alternative to `DNS.GetHostName()` when it is the `Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName)` function which actually throws? Or does the `DNS.GetHostName()` fail to give you the correct hostname?

Comment: The error says No such host is known which is an expected error from Dns.GetHostEntry if the host name is not valid. My assumption is that Dns.GetHostName is the one which retrieve host name in incorrect format and thus resulting GetHostEntry to throw an exception. Hope that helps.